# how can the value of private instance variables of a class change in java

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, memory-management, collections

```
class ProductSpec{
    private List<Item> items;

    public ProductSpec(){}

    getItems(Long id){
        return itemRepository.getAllByProductId(id)
    }


    getProductDetails(Parameters parameters){
//LOGIC...
//....
        Long productId = //fetched from api get request params
        items = getItems(productId); //LINE A
        items.forEach(i->System.out.println(i.getId + " " + i.getProductId())); //LINE B

        doStuff(items);
    }




    private doStuff(items){
        items.forEach(
            i->{
                System.out.println(i.getId() + " "+ i.getProductId()) //LINE C
            }
        )
    }
}
```

let's consider the example code above,
I have two set of item list IN database as follows

Items for product id=1
| items id | product id |
| -------- | --------   |
| 101      |  1         |
| 102      |  1         |

Items for product id=2
| items id | product id |
| -------- | --------   |
| 103      |  2         |
| 104      |  2         |

Behaviour in production is as follows

when the product id=1, LINE B prints- 101 1 , 102 1
but some how LINE C prints -  103 1, 104 1 (in some cases)
The items instance variable is not reassigned any where after LINE A
How is this possible?

tried returning the Collection.unmodifiableList(items) in LINE A.
this did not solve the problem. What could be wrong here

Comment: You have a constructor A in class ProductSpec. none of this will compile. ever heard of setters or other mutators?

Comment: Perhaps another thread calls `getProductDetails`?

Comment: @tgdavies yes, how can I make sure that the value of items remain unchanged for a product

Comment: Make `items` a local variable in `getProductDetails` instead of a field.

Comment: @tgdavies, I understand our point, but items is being used by multiple methods in the same class hence it is an instance variable. Also since it is a db call, want to avoid getItems call directly. Is there any other way?

Comment: How did you wrap a `List` with `Collection.unmodifiableMap(items)`?

Comment: @Stultuske I have corrected the constructor, please note this is a dummy code equivalent to an existing production code. Please advise.

Comment: @tgdavies my bad , used this  Collection.unmodifiableList(items)

Comment: How does the items field get populated? You should edit the code in the question so that it at least compiles, and that all code that touches the items field is shown.

Comment: It could be (for example if `ProductSpec` is a bean in a Spring context) that your application only uses a single instance of `ProductSpec` to serve all client requests. In such a case different requests occuring at the same time would overwrite each others `items`. The solution in that case would be to not store request-specific data in fields.

Comment: You need to decide what the semantics of a `ProductSpec` instance are. Perhaps `items` should be a `Map<Integer,List<Item>>`.

Comment: @ashvini nobody expects you to post production code, but at least a minimal reproducable example of the problem.

Comment: LINE A is not a return statement at all, so the sentence “*tried returning the Collection.unmodifiableList(items) in LINE A*” makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways the result of printing the values in the objects in the list referred to by the `items` field can change.

1. A new `List<Item>` is assigned to the `items` field. This happens every time `getProductDetails` is called, and may happen in other places you haven't shown.
2. Objects are added to/removed from the list whose reference is stored in `items`. We don't see this happening in the code you've shown, but anything with the `items` reference can do this. If the reference in `items` was to an immutable list, then this source of change wouldn't be possible.
3. The values of fields in the objects in the list whose reference is stored in `items` can be changed by setters on the `Item` class (or other methods).

While the above answers the question you ask in your post, what you want to know is "why doesn't my code do what I want it to do?"

You haven't provided enough information to answer that question, but most probably you have created `ProductSpec` without deciding what it does. You have mutable state (the `items` field) and judging by the use of the multithreading tag, you have several threads using the same `ProductSpec` instance. That is simply not going to work.